# Django use a column as keys another as values and return dictionary

Tags: django, django-models

In Django I have a table within a model like:

```
key value
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   4
b   5
```

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to return:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}
```

or:

```
[{'key': 'a', 'values': [1, 2, 3]}, {'key': 'b', 'values': [4, 5]}]
```

This can be done in Python easily by just iterating through all entries of the table.

But since I discovered [Aggregation | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/), I wonder if this can be done in Django directly, without writing Python loops?

Comment: I feel this is a kind of *concatenation* rather than *aggregation*

Comment: Could you add your model class to the question please?

Comment: @RHSmith159 Alright added.